# Différence entre « Restreindre », « Contraindre » et « Astreindre »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, phonétique

J'ai croisé pour la première fois aujourd'hui le verbe « Astreindre » dans la phrase suivante :

> C'est en vertu du Règlement sur le programme de prévention que les six (6) groupes sont **astreints** aux articles de la Loi sur la santé et sécurité du travail qui s'applique progressivement.

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/astreindre) indique que c'est un synonyme des verbes *contraindre*, *assujettir*, *obliger*. D'autre part, j'ai l'impression qu'il peut parfois être remplacer par le verbe *restreindre*, comme dans ce cas :

> Je suis **restreint** à partager mon déjeuner.
>
> Je suis **astreint** à partager mon déjeuner.
>
> Je suis **contraint** à partager mon déjeuner.

Ces verbes me semblent avoir un sens commun, une phonétique semblable, mais pourtant je ne peux m'empêcher de croire qu'il y a une différence entre ces verbes. Quel est-elle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Restreindre* implique qu'une contrainte cause la *diminution* de quelque chose. On ne peut pas dire *je suis restreint à partager mon déjeuner*, parce que le partage n'est pas une diminution. Par contre on peut dire *je suis restreint à un seul repas par jour*, ce qui signifie que je voudrais en prendre plus d'un par jour mais ne peux pas.

*Astreindre* et *contraindre* sont plus similaires l'un à l'autre. Le préfixe "a-" dans astreindre indique que c'est le sujet du verbe qui impose volontairement la contrainte sur l'objet ; il implique la volonté du sujet, ou de quelqu'un en général à la forme passive.

On peut donc dire indifféremment :

> Le policier m'a astreint à quitter ma voiture
>
> Le policier m'a contraint à quitter ma voiture
>
> J'ai été astreint [par le policier] à quitter la voiture.
>
> J'ai été contraint [par le policier] de quitter la voiture

(*Contraindre à* ou *contraindre de* peuvent tous deux être utilisés indifféremment pour introduire un groupe verbal à l'infinitif ; pour astreindre, c'est toujours *à* qui s'emploie.)

On peut également dire:

> La pluie m'a contraint à ouvrir mon parapluie.

Mais on ne peut pas dire:

> La pluie m'a astreint à ouvrir mon parapluie. **
>
> À cause de la pluie, j'ai été astreint à ouvrir mon parapluie. **

car ce serait attribuer une volonté à la pluie.

De plus, en tout cas personnellement, "astreindre" semble être associé avec une vague connotation de légitimité. Un bandit peut *contraindre* sa victime à faire quelque chose, mais on n'utilisera pas souvent d'*astreindre* dans ce cas-là ; par contre, et comme dans l'exemple, une loi, un réglement, un supérieur, etc. peuvent *astreindre* quelqu'un à faire quelque chose, étant sous-entendu que cela fait partie des prérogatives du sujet.

Enfin il y a des constructions particulières comme *astreindre à domicile* (forcer quelqu'un à rester chez soi) qui ne s'emploient qu'avec un seul des verbes.

Comment: Mais pourrait-on dire « J'ai restreint mon déjeuner pour le partager. » ?

Comment: On pourrait dire quelque chose comme *je me suis restreint à ne manger qu'une partie de mon déjeuner afin de pouvoir le partager*.

Comment: Et pour ce qui est de la différence entre contraindre et astreindre, pourrait-on dire « La pluie m'a contraint à ouvrir mon parapluie » ? Le verbe contraindre implique t'il aussi la volonté du sujet ?

Comment: Cette phrase est correcte, le verbe contraindre n'implique pas la volonté du sujet

Comment: (Ajouté à la réponse.)